# Make pairs out of a list in erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to do a process on items in a sorted set in erlang, I call `ZRANGE KEY 0 -1 WITHSCORES` with eredis, the problem is it returns something like `[<<"item1">>, <<"100">>, <<"item2">>, <<"200">>]`. How can I run a function f on these items efficiently so that these calls occur: `f(<<"item1">>, <<"100">>)`, `f(<<"item2">>, <<"200">>)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with something like this

```
f([X,Y|T]) -> [do_the_job(X,Y)|f(T)];
f([]) -> [].
```

then calling:

```
f(List).
```

Is there a more efficient way for doing so?

Comment: You should probably call the function directly instead of just pairing it up first.  Also you would probably use a tuple if you really want pairing up.  The tail recursive version from the other answer would only be faster on ancient versions of Erlang no one uses anymore.

Answer (score 0):

An optimized way is using tail-recursion. You can pass your list into `do/1` function and it generates an empty list for storing the result of applying `f/2` function on each two head items of the given list and then return the results:

```
do(List) ->
   do(List, []).
do([X,Y | Tail], Acc) ->
   do(Tail, [f(X, Y) | Acc]);
do([], Acc) ->
   lists:reverse(Acc).

f(X, Y) ->
   {X, Y}.
```

---

A note from [Erlang documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html) about tail-recursive efficiency:

> In most cases, a recursive function uses more words on the stack for each recursion than the number of words a tail-recursive would allocate on the heap. As more memory is used, the garbage collector is invoked more frequently, and it has more work traversing the stack.

Comment: Note the paragraph next to the one cited:In R12B and later releases, there is an optimization that in many cases reduces the number of words used on the stack in body-recursive calls. A body-recursive list function and a tail-recursive function that calls lists:reverse/1 at the end will use the same amount of memory. lists:map/2, lists:filter/2, list comprehensions, and many other recursive functions now use the same amount of space as their tail-recursive equivalents.

Comment: So baseline: it doesn't matter anymore

Comment: Also your code returns a reversed list  which is probably not intended, I'll add the reverse not to confuse anyone